# One Objects record is need to be Updated in another Object

Tags: trigger

```
    trigger UpdateChangeLog on Dealsheet__c (after update) {
    //List<Id> ChangeLog = new List<Id>();
        for(Dealsheet__c deal : trigger.new){

    List<String> ListChangeLog =
       [select name,Amended_Version__c,Amended_Verssion_Sent_To_CP__c,Broker__c,Broker_s_Name__c,Brokerage_Per_MMBTU__c,
                                    BU_Contract__c, Buy_Sell__c,Confirmation_Email_Sent__c,Counter_Party_Name__c,CP_Address__c,CP_Address_Line1__c,
                                    CP_Address_Line2__c,CP_Confirm_Email__c,CP_ZIP_Code__c,Create_Date__c,End_Date__c,External_Comments__c,
                                        Fixed_Price__c,Instrument__c,Internal_Comments__c,Internal_Trader__c,Link_ID__c,Meter_Name__c,Price__c,
                                    PriceIndex__c,Price_Type__c,ReSend_Email__c,Start_Date__c,Strategy__c,    Terms_Condition__c,Total_Volume__c,Tradebook__c,Trade_Date__c,
                                    Vlm_Day__c from Change_Log__c where id = :deal.Change_Log__c];

    for(Change_Log__c Changelog1 : ListChangeLog)
    {
        Changelog1.name = deal.Name;
        Changelog1.Amended_Version__c = deal.Amended_Version__c;
        changelog1.Meter_Name__c= deal.Meter_Name__c;

    }

    }
     update Changelog1;


}
```

I have used this trigger to update the Change_Log__c object but in this I am getting error  "Variable does not exist: Changelog1 "

How to do this please tell me
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hi srihari, welcome to SFSE! Please [edit] your question when you have information to add. Do not post `Answers` to your question which aren't answers. Do not ask duplicate `Questions`. Do not leave comments. Editing your post as was intended will help us keep the quality of content in our community high. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

ChangeLog1 is a local variable , you can not access ChangeLog1 from out side of for loop.
Change the code update operation like below:

```
update ListChangeLog;
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to use the for loop variable out side the end of braces thus it is giving the error it should be

```
trigger UpdateChangeLog on Dealsheet__c (after update) {
//List<Id> ChangeLog = new List<Id>();
static boolean flag = true;
Set<Id> dealIdSet = new Set<Id>();
for(Dealsheet__c deal : trigger.new){
    dealIdSet.add(deal.Change_Log__c);
}

List<String> ListChangeLog =   [select name,Amended_Version__c,Amended_Verssion_Sent_To_CP__c,Broker__c,Broker_s_Name__c,Brokerage_Per_MMBTU__c,BU_Contract__c,Buy_Sell__c,Confirmation_Email_Sent__c,Counter_Party_Name__c,CP_Address__c,CP_Address_Line1__c,    CP_Address_Line2__c,CP_Confirm_Email__c,CP_ZIP_Code__c,Create_Date__c,End_Date__c,External_Comments__c,
                                Fixed_Price__c,Instrument__c,Internal_Comments__c,Internal_Trader__c,Link_ID__c,Meter_Name__c,Price__c,                      PriceIndex__c,Price_Type__c,ReSend_Email__c,Start_Date__c,Strategy__c,    Terms_Condition__c,Total_Volume__c,Tradebook__c,Trade_Date__c,Vlm_Day__c from Change_Log__c where id In dealIdSet];
If(ListChangeLog != null){
    for(Change_Log__c Changelog1 : ListChangeLog)
    {
    Changelog1.name = deal.Name;
    Changelog1.Amended_Version__c = deal.Amended_Version__c;
    changelog1.Meter_Name__c= deal.Meter_Name__c;
   }
}
if(flag){
    flag = false;
update ListChangeLog;

}
}
```

I have removed the query from for loop according to the best practice and to avoid recursion have used static flag variable

let me know if this does not work.

Comment: hi kalpesh it is not working error Variable does not exist: deal.Name

Comment: Apologies I took the deal variable outside kindly use map to bind the deal sheet record with change log and then update the list so that it does not update others data on other change log.